# Eloquent does not retrieve mysql table that I imported as csv, but Query Builder does

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv, eloquent

In Laravel application `$model = Model::all()` was working fine with data inserted manually in MySQL, but when I imported data from csv table, Eloquent does not retrieve the table content anymore, with no error.
I tried with `DB::table('table_name')->get()` and works fine, but I want to use Eloquent.
Can anyone help me, please!

Comment: Try `Model::firstOrFail()` and read the exception

Comment: I tried and "No query results for model _Model_"

Comment: What are the table name and model name called exactly?

Comment: Can you show your actual `DB` query and the contents of your model?

Comment: Seems that the problem is in mysql. When I import csv, the **deleted_at** field, created for softDeletes, becomes 0000-00-00, even if it's declare as default NULL. `Model::all()` only retrieves records when **deleted_at** is NULL.

Comment: I asked another question(updated ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342778/in-laravel-application-mysql-import-transforms-timestamp-null-values-to-0000-00

Answer (score 2):

Your table name should be `names` (plural) and your model should be `Name`. Read more at: [Model Naming Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Or if you don't want to change your table name, simply put in your model a protected property `table`.

```
protected $table = 'name'; //This way the model will know which table it should use.
```